# How to redirect a page from one blueprint view to another?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, blueprint

I am using Flask along with the Blueprint module. In my application, I am trying to redirect the page to `page/home` after a successful login (`user/login`) using LDAP but the redirect takes forever without throwing any error.

I tried a couple of different variations of `redirect(url_for('page.home'))`, `redirect(url_for('page/home.html'))`. But each of these commands do not redirect. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Kindly help.

Folder structure:

[image]

user/views.py:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, session
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM

from snakeeyes.blueprints.page.views import page

import config.settings as p

user = Blueprint('user', __name__, template_folder='templates')
user.secret_key = 'dev key'

# @user.route('/')
# @user.route('/login')
# def login():
#     return render_template('user/login.html')

def connect_ldap(username, password):
    if not username or not password:
        return False
    # try:
    #     from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM
    # except ImportError as importException:
    #     print("LDAP3 import not found, run 'sudo pip install ldap3 && sudo pip3 install ldap3'")
    #     print(importException)
    #     return False

    # define the server
    server = Server('us01ds', port=389,  get_info=ALL)

    # define the connection
    user = 'uid=%s,ou=people,ou=users,dc=global,dc=COMPANY,dc=com' % username
    conn = Connection(server, user, password, auto_bind=True)

    # perform the Bind operation
    if not conn.bind():
        print('error in bind', conn.result)
        return False
    else:
        return True


@user.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@user.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # global username
    # username = None

    # If POST, redirect to dashboard
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username'].encode('utf8').decode("utf-8")
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf8').decode("utf-8")

        # Try to login using ldap
        test = connect_ldap(username, password)

        # Invalid credentials
        if not test:
            return render_template(
                'login.html',
                isinvalid='is-invalid',
                error='Username or Password is incorrect'
            )
        else:
            # session['user_id'] = request.form['username']
            print('redict to home page')
            return redirect(url_for('page.home'))

    # If GET, render the login page
    else:
        return render_template('user/login.html')
```

page/views.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

page = Blueprint('page', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@page.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('page/home.html')


@page.route('/terms')
def terms():
    return render_template('page/terms.html')


@page.route('/privacy')
def privacy():
    return render_template('page/privacy.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this problem.

In order to better facilitate the generation of URLs that make use of an HTTPS URL
scheme this patch adds a parameter with this specific purpose in mind. To
achieve this we explicitly pass in a param, `_scheme='https'`, and then set the
`url_scheme` attribute of our `MapAdapter` instance appropriately.

Importantly, `_external=True` must be set in order for this to work properly.
As such, failure to do so results in a `ValueError` being raised.

So, I just replace `return redirect(url_for('page.home'))`  => `return redirect(url_for('page.home', _external=True, _scheme='https'))`

Reference: https://github.com/pallets/flask/commit/b5069d07a24a3c3a54fb056aa6f4076a0e7088c7